# How can I Xor two decimal numbers?

Tags: logic, binary

I want to take two numbers, say 200 and 101, and transform them into their binary form. Then XOR them together and transform the result back into the decimal form. The result in this case should be 173.

I tried to play with the `BaseForm[200, 2]` and `BaseForm[101, 2]`. However, I cannot work with the result. I also tried the operator `Xor`, for example, `Xor[1, 1]`, but it returns `False` instead of `0`.

Any idea?

Comment: `BitXor` is intended for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a = 200;
b = 101;
ceiling = Max@(Ceiling@Log2@# & /@ {a, b})
abin = IntegerDigits[a, 2, ceiling]
bbin = IntegerDigits[b, 2, ceiling]

FromDigits[BitXor[abin, bbin], 2]
```

> 173

Comment: `BitXor[200, 101]` would also do it but sometimes things get more involved with the masking going on.

Comment: Thank you I've got it.